# Change activity details during use of ActivityScenarioRule

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm using ActivityScenarioRule to run tests of my activities. Each activity has its own view model, which gets created within onCreate-method.
I would like to test same activity with different scenarios, so that's why I came up to replace activity's view model with a mocked one.

Because ActivityScenarioRule is annotated with @Rule, I'm not able to change the behaviour. It's possible to start activity with an intent (which passes the mocked view model), but this needs to be done within a static method, which is bad, because I want to replace view model for each test independently.

ActivityScenarioRule.getScenario().onActivity won't work, because activity is started and activity's onCreate was already called. It would be possible to replace the view model and restart activity, but since onCreate is called all the time, "original" view model is executed too, which is bad when dealing with network.

Replacing my original activity with a mocked one (which will use internally the mocked view model) won't work either, because it needs to be declared within manifest file.

Last but not least, I could implement my own test runner, but this bad too, because I need to tell the runner which view model I want to use.

Deprecated ActivityTestRule seems to be suit better here, but I can't imagine, that things went worse than better.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are running up against a common problem which is that `ActivityScenario` does not allow you to control how the activity gets created. This has some feature requests such as https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/433 and https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/1738 but it seems Google don't care about it. The best bet for now is to use intents, or postpone the initialization until after `onCreate` and just replace the view model inside an `onActivity` block.